# if non-empty file compare columns and write matching lines to new file

Tags: perl

I want to write a script that does the following: the user can choose to import a .txt file (for this I have written the code)(here `$list1`). This file consists of only one column with names on each line. If the user imported a file which is not empty, than I want to compare the names from a column from another file (here `$file2`) with the names in the imported file. I there is a match, then the whole line of this original file (`$file2`) should be placed in a new file (`$filter1`).

This is what I have so far:

```
my $list1;

if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import a genelist for filtering?")){
    my $genelist1 = prompt("Give the name of the first genelist file:\n");
    open($list1,'+<',$genelist1) or die "Could not open file $genelist1 $!";
}

open(my $filter1,'+>',"filter1.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!";

my %hash1=();
while(<$list1>){ # $list1 is the variable from the imported .txt file
    chomp;    
    next unless -z $_;
    my $keyfield= $_; # this imported file contains only one column
    $hash1{$keyfield}++;
}

seek $file2,0,0; #cursor resetting
while(<$file2>){ # this is the other file with multiple columns
    my @line=split(/\t/);  # split on tabs
    my $keyfield=$line[2]; # values to compare are in column 3       
    if (exists($hash1{$keyfield})){
    print $filter1 $_;
    }       
}
```

When running this script my output `filter1.txt` is empty. Which is not correct because there are definitely matches between the columns.

Comment: you could also give example of input and output, but then again you can run script yourself and verify if it does what you want.

Comment: The code as you have shown it won't work (where does `$line[0]` come from, for example?).  Does your actual code work?

Comment: I suppose `$list1` is a filehandle, it is better to use `-z` or `-s` to check for an empty filehandle of size instead of what you are doing here. In your first while loop, just build your hash instead of using `push`. In your second while loop, you can do something like `while (<$file2>) { my $k = (split /\t/)[1]; if ( grep {/$k/} keys %hash1 ) { print $filter1 $_; } }`

Comment: @hwnd $list1 is indeed a filehandle. I changed the script based on your comments & added the code to show you where $list1 comes from. I did this because when I now execute my code I get an error message saying that $list1 requires an explicit package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have declared the $list1 filehandle as a lexical ( "my" ) variable inside a block, it is only visible in that block.

So the later lines in your script can't see $list1 and it gives the error message mentioned

To fix this, declare $list1 before the if.. block that opens the file

As the script stands, doesn't set keys or values in %hash1

Your spec is fuzzy, but what you might be intending is loading hash1 keys from file1

```
while(<$list1>){            # $list1 is the variable from the imported .txt file
    chomp;                  # remove newlines
    my $keyfield=$_;        # this imported file contains only one column
    $hash1{$keyfield}++;    # this sets a key in %hash1
    }
```

Then when going through file2

```
while(<$file2>){                      # this is the other file with multiple columns
    my @line=split(/\t/);             # split on tabs
    my $keyfield=$line[2];            # values to compare are in column "2"      
    if (exists($hash1{$keyfield}) ){  # do hash lookup for exact match
        print $_;                     # output entire line
    }
```

Incidentally, $line[2] is actually column 3, the first column is $line[0], the second $line[1] etc

If you actually want to do a partial or pattern match (like a grep) then using a hash isn't appropriate

Finally, you will have to amend the `print $_; # output entire line` to output to a file, if this is what you require.  I removed the reference to $filter1 as this isn't declared in the script fragment shown

Comment: I edited my script (see question). However, my outputfile is empty now, which it shouldn't be, since there are matches between the columns. I had this problem before so therefore I added the `seek` for cursor resetting, since this `file2` has been used in a `while` loop before.

Comment: ``next unless -z $_;``  looks for files with the filename of the lines in file1.  The ``next`` is always going to happen unless there happens to be a zero sized file with that exact name.  I am guessing there are no such zero sized files so it is unlikely that any data gets into the %hash1.  Delete this line and see what happens